# How to know if a CNN model has overfitting or underfitting by looking at graph

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, multiclass-classification

[image]
I get this graphe, please can you help me?
How can i know if it's overfitting or underfitting ?

Comment: it seems accuarcy reaches an upper threshold, this means the model learns, but it can possibly overfit as well

Answer (score 1):

When the training loss is much lower than validation loss, the network might be overfitted and can not be generalized to unseen data.
When the training loss is high, it means the network couldn't learn the training data set and the training didn't go well and this is underfitting. Underfitting usually happens when the dataset is high-dimension, and the number of samples is not enough for the model to learn it.

Comment: "When the training loss is much lower than validation loss, the network might be overfitted and can not be generalized to unseen data (like the picture on the right)" in some epochs (incl. the last set of epochs) val loss is lower than train loss. Why would you still consider this overfitting?

Comment: right! changed the answer. Thank you @Sammy!

Comment: Thank you @Sammy, your answer so helpful  to me. You make it clearer.